# How to deploy laravel and vuejs serparately in apache server

Tags: web-deployment

I have an application laravel as backend and vuejs as frontend separately. The problem is I don't know how to deploy this app to the server separately using apache server. I need help please provide me a detail instructions on how to do it. I have successfully deploy the laravel application api but I'm having trouble with the vuejs frontend also I'm using one ip address for this two application.

Thanks for your help.
Donnie.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to deploy **Vue SPA** on the apache server.

Run this command in your project for production build

> npm run prod

**OR**

> yarn build

This command will create a dist folder in your **Vue** project.

> project/dist/spa

spa folder contains index.html and other files (images,css and compiled js filed)
[image]

Give path of this index.html in your apache environment.

> /etc/apache2/sites-available/your_project.conf

In ubuntu look like this.

> eg /var/www/dist/spa

In ubuntu how we make the symbolic link

> ln -s /your_project/dist    /var/www/dist

Comment: How about my laravel backend you mean I need to setup my apache2 configuration. Here's my <VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName localhost
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/testvueappdeploy/dist
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html/testvueappdeploy/dist/public>
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
and also do I need another virtual host configuration for my api or just run this command? or i used symbolic link.